# How to use jasmine toMatch multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

How can I test if a variable will match multiple options in Jasmine?
I want to do something like this, where I am checking if taxonomyType matches one of three options 'GEM', 'PAGER' or 'ATC58':

```
expect(taxonomyType).toMatch({'GEM', 'PAGER', 'ATC58'});
```

Comment: Check [Included Matchers](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Included_Matchers). You could use a regular expression for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reverse it and use `toContain`

```
var a = ['GEM', 'PAGER', 'ATC58'];  
expect(a).toContain(taxonomyType);
```

Or you could write your own loop (or use lodash/underscore) to determine "found" and compare the result to true/false

```
expect(_.includes(['GEM', 'PAGER', 'ATC58'], taxonomyType)).toBe(true);
```

Comment: `- Failed: _ is not defined` Do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: @RafaelC. import `underscore.js` (it's an entire library, like jQuery)